# How to compile separate assembly files together?

Tags: assembly, linker, ld, gnu-assembler

To put into perspective, I'm writing a simple bootloader but I want to separate my source code into multiple assembly files and link them together. Each file has its own section to put them in a desired memory location. Long story short, my problem here is that from file "file_2.s" I want to access the labels from "file_1.s" (for example the BPB), but there are many labels so to declare them as `.global` is not an option. The problem is that if I refer to a label from an other source file, I get:

> undeclared reference to ...

What I don't get is that if I write my bootloader into ONE single file with multiple sections, it compiles fine but not if I compile every file into an object file and link them together.  Can someone give me the options that I have, to compile every file into its own object file, link them together and still be able to refer to their labels from one section to another? Maybe have every label declared as global?

Just to add to it, using the option `-relocatable` is not possible because I'm outputting a binary file and not an ELF file.

Comment: `.global` is there for this reason. You do not normally want all your labels in one file to be visible and therefore possibly conflict with labels in a different file. Also, you generally only want to mark the labels that are part of the public API of the file, so that you know what parts you can change. One option is to use a macro that both defines the label and marks it as global so you can do something like `GLOBAL(foo)`. Alternatively you can set up your build system to turn all locals into globals via `nm` and `objcopy` (not recommended).

Comment: NASM has `%include`, perhaps you can use a similar directive for your assembler. This results in the assembly functioning as if all the content was in the same file, but still allows to actually read it from several files.

Comment: You already know the answer.  It's to make your labels global.

Comment: @ecm: Yes, GAS has a `.include "path"` directive (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Include.html), and GAS is often used with the C preprocessor (`gcc -c foo.S`) which can `#include "path"`.

Comment: @Jester  as I said, I have a BPB with like 15-20 labels and declare them as global seemed to me really not really “standard”, maybe I should just write everything in one file just for the labels that I need, but again I initially ask this question because I thought I was doing something wrong. I’ll try the GLOBAL thing and get back to you. Just to add, I’m using the GNU assembler…

Comment: Any label you want to reference from a separately-assembled (not `.include`d) file needs to be `.global`.  It doesn't have any bad effects other than that, and is totally normal if for some reason you can't just put something small like that in the same file.  For a BPB as part of a legacy BIOS MBR bootloader, `.include` might be appropriate since the whole thing is at most 512 bytes of code+data.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but since this morning I'm trying to use the .include directive but I still get the `undefined reference to` error.  If I use the `.include` directive on both of my files, then it works but the BPB part is copied twice in memory...

Just to be sure, using the `.include` directive makes the labels sort of global right ? But only on those labels are only available on the file that did the ".include" and not the other files passed to LD right ?

Comment: If you use `.include` that works as if you had written the contents of the file right there in place of the directive. So yeah, if you use that in multiple files, you will get multiple copies. The idea is to use `.include` instead of multiple object files that are linked together.

Comment: Put another way, `.include` does the exact same thing that copying the entire file to your clipboard and pasting it directly into your other file would.